# Pros and cons: Jetbrains IntelliJ / Sublime Text

Tags: java, php, javascript, ide

I'm looking for a IDE that supports PHP/JAVA/CSS/HTML/JAVASCRIPT and possibly other languages.

[Jetbrains IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com) both seem like good choices.

However, since both require a payment for continued use, I'd like to know what the pros and cons of these two IDE's are, so as to get a better idea of which would be right for me. I'd like, not having to learn how to use both.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org)? It is free and open source.

Comment: Id go with Eclipse i think it has more varied language support than Netbeans. But either are good for PHP and Java. Ive also used eclipse with Ruby before.

Comment: IntelliJ has a free community edition.

Comment: I would add, that if you have an old or slow computer then Sublime might be better, even on my 8GB PC using Sublime seems so much faster than all other IDEs. If this is not an issue then WebStorm is better.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First off all, IntelliJ is an IDE, where as Sublime Text is a text editor. This difference means a lot when you want to work with languages like Java, that has a lot of syntactic bagages, but is quite productive with good IDE support.

In my experience an IDE focuses on adding support for much of the tooling involved around developing in a specific language, for instance build tools, debuggers, test runners etc. In addition an IDE is very useful when you work in statically typed languages, because the safe refactoring support you get is really productive.

A good text editor on the other hand focuses on manipulating text (although editors like Emacs is almost an OS in and of itself), and so thats where it's greatest strengths lies. Really investing to learn a good editor makes you look like a "text surgeon".

Some people claim that there is little value add with an IDE for working with dynamic languages, but after having used tools like WebStorm and RubyMine I disagree.

To generalize, an IDE provides you with a really productive environment out-of-the box, where as an editor usually needs to be customized to fit your specific work-flow. That also means that text-editors are more customizable, and can be configure to fit your specific needs more so than an IDE.

Personally I feel most productive in an IDE, but when I look at people really proficient in VIM or Emacs, I can't help wondering wether I should invest the time learning the tools.

I highly recomend watching the [Play by Play](http://peepcode.com/) and [Destroy all Software](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts) screencasts for  examples of developers that really have invested in learning and customizing their text editor.

Comment: Thanks for all this helpful information :)

Comment: I use JetBrains IDEs for JavaScript and am very happy with them. If you don't require PHP/Ruby/Java etc. then I'd recommend WebStorm because it's the cheapest IDE they do and has the same excellent JavaScript/HTML/CSS support as their other IDEs.

Comment: The biggest gains for javascript come with Intellij's realtime JSLint checking, autocompletion, and command-click indexing.  I always recommend that people try an editor all by itself for at least two weeks to see what the advantages are of that editor.

Comment: I use IntelliJ with the VIM plugin, and it's great to combine the power of both tools.

Comment: A good response, but it misses a big point: An IDE typically contains a text editor as one of it's (many) tools.  IDEA has a very, very good text editor.

Answer (score 14):

**I would definitely go with Jetbrains IntelliJ.**

Sublime Text is pretty nice, but it doesn't have auto-completion for libraries and doesn't give a real code navigation functionality. It does have code completion based on the language and also records the typed instructions.

It doesn't support interactive debuggers.

It cannot be considered an IDE.

It's a beta product.

On the other hand, IntelliJ has the best of an full featured IDE including UML diagrams, local history/versioning (You don't need to keep saving your code, it does it automatically), GIT and SVN integration, an amazing error checking while you code, documentation support, hints for the language, and even spell checker for the docs, variables, classes and method names.

Both provides trial versions. Why not try it out and see by yourself?

You could also give a try to Netbeans and Eclipse.

Comment: I'm now going to move back to Sublime from Inellij IDEA because I like Sublime autocompletion more than IDEA's

Answer (score 6):

Sublime Text is a text editor; only IntelliJ is an IDE, so there you go.